# Mahalanobis distance between two columns containing two variables

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

Good evening, I'd like to calculate the Mahalanobis distance between each observation of the two vectors `(O_Temp, O_Salin)` and `(D_Temp, D_Salin)` in the attached image.

So, the aim is to calculate the Mahalanobis distance between the column vector `(O_Temp, O_salin)` and the column vector `(D_Temp, D_Salin)` for all observations (over 3 million observations).

I've tried a Mahalanobis pairwise but it doesn't work. Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large. No data in images. Also include all relevant code, and any error or warning messages, again as plain text.

Comment: I am unsure about what is meant by *between the column vector (O_Temp, O_salin) and the column vector (D_Temp, D_Salin)*. You may need to split your matrix in two matrices of size 3*1e6 x 2. This is an interesing source: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65705/pairwise-mahalanobis-distances An `{Rcpp}` implementation should be straightforward.

Comment: Perhaps something like `m <- cbind(O_Temp, O_Salin); mahalanobis(m, colMeans(m), var(m))`

Comment: I'm not looking for  the distance between each pair of ports (Origin port and Destination port) having as variables (Temperature and Salinity), hence the name of the O and D variables. So the mean vector must be the column vector (D_Temp, D_Salin) and must vary (equal to the number of osbervation = 3 million observations). I've already done it, setting the colMean for a single vector. but here there are 3 million vectors. so I want to find a solution to change the colMean for each observation, colMeans= vector (D_Temp, D_Salin). any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. We can make use of the `mahalanobis()` function in base R.
2. We need beside the observations, a mean vector and the covariance matrix of the dataset.
3. As the Mahalanobis distance is generally used to measure the distance of a point from a distribution (mean and covariance), we first calculate the distance between each pair of points.
4. Finally wie calculate the pvalue.

The original how to is from [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/08/how-to-calculate-mahalanobis-distance-in-r/)

```
# example dataset
df <- data.frame(
  O_Temp = c(20.976270078546495, 24.30378732744839, 22.055267521432878, 20.897663659937937, 18.473095986778095),
  O_Salin = c(31.403935408357594, 28.772030269246407, 39.767476761184525, 22.04089621496056, 24.177535121896696),
  D_Temp = c(23.556330735924604, 15.400159463843297, 24.703880442451897, 29.243770902348764, 14.97506287039916),
  D_Salin = c(22.988966093159874, 37.36252114736428, 23.249858693527496, 32.311191285676884, 22.476399656988832)
)

observations <- data.frame(Temperature = df$O_Temp - df$D_Temp, 
                           Salinity = df$O_Salin - df$D_Salin)

mean_vector <- colMeans(observations)
cov_matrix <- cov(observations)

df$Mahalanobis_Distance <- mahalanobis(observations, center = mean_vector, cov = cov_matrix)
df$pvalue <- pchisq(df$Mahalanobis_Distance, df=2, lower.tail = FALSE)
df
```

```
O_Temp  O_Salin   D_Temp  D_Salin Mahalanobis_Distance    pvalue
1 20.97627 31.40394 23.55633 22.98897            0.4343278 0.8047981
2 24.30379 28.77203 15.40016 37.36252            2.3763608 0.3047753
3 22.05527 39.76748 24.70388 23.24986            1.7669273 0.4133487
4 20.89766 22.04090 29.24377 32.31119            3.0919451 0.2131045
5 18.47310 24.17754 14.97506 22.47640            0.3304390 0.8477076
```

Comment: why do you use `apply`? `mahalanobis` function is vectorized. No need of apply

Comment: @Onyambu. Did not recognized it. Many thanks. I have corrected it in the script!